# Wp get archive only text not link

Tags: functions

i use this function

```
wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'yearly', 'limit' => 12, 'format' => 'html' ) );
```

And i got this:

```
<a title="2013" href="http://wordpress11.localhost/?m=2013">2013</a>
```

I need only "2013". Just anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Totally trying this, how about:

```
wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'yearly', 'limit' => 12, 'format' => 'custom', 'before' => '<span class="year">', 'after' => '</span>' ) );
```